# Convert list of lists into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dataframe

I have dataframe in this format. There are total 907 rows in dataframe and 2 columns named as Audio and Sentence. The audio column contains a lists of lists as you can see. The total length of this list is 10000.

```
Audio                                                     sentence
[[-0.32357552647590637], [-0.4721883237361908],.....],the kind of them is a relative all the little old lady is it to confide in them and head for buying them hate it consists of a vertical schrock
 [[-0.32357552647590637],[-0.4721883237361908],.....]]the kind of them is a relative all the little old lady is it to confide in them and head for buying them hate it consists of a vertical schrock
```

I tried to convert list into dataframe but it seprates each character which is not my goal.

```
aa= pd.DataFrame.from_records(X_tra)
```

it does something like this.

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ...     269990  269991  269992  269993  269994  269995  269996  269997  269998  269999
0   [   [   0   .   0   0   3   9   1   1   ...     None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
```

```
Audio                                                     sentence
[[-0.32357552647590637], [-0.4721883237361908],.....],the kind of them is a relative all the little old lady is it to confide in them and head for buying them hate it consists of a vertical schrock
 [[-0.32357552647590637],[-0.4721883237361908],.....]]the kind of them is a relative all the little old lady is it to confide in them and head for buying them hate it consists of a vertical schrock
```

above given output is actual output.
The expected output is given below.

```
Audio                  Audio1                    sentence
-0.32357552647590637 -0.4721883237361908 ..... the kind of them is a relative all the little old lady is it to confide in them and head for buying them hate it consists of a vertical schrock
-0.32357552647590637 -0.4721883237361908 ......the kind of them is a relative all the little old lady is it to confide in them and head for buying them hate it consists of a vertical schrock
```

I want to use this output to train Neural netowrk so my sentence column will be Y and rest of dataframe will be X.

Comment: what is the `x_tra` and `from_records` ?

Comment: @MKPatel X_tra = X_train.tolist()
The original Audio column is pandas series. so I converted it into list

Comment: it mean that it will give you list of list of your audio right?

Comment: Yes, the output of my code is given.

Comment: yes got it i am trying to solve your error

Comment: Do the lists in `Audio` have the same length?

Comment: @DarrenChristopher yes the length is same.

Answer (score 1):

what about this solution?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'Audio':[[[-0.32357552647590637],[-0.4721883237361908]], [[-0.32357552647590637], [-0.4721883237361908]]],
        'sentence':['the kind of them is a relative all the little old', 'More text']})

audios = data.Audio.apply(lambda x: np.ravel(np.array(x))).apply(pd.Series)
audios.columns = ['Audio'+ str(i) for i in range(len(audios.columns))]

audios['sentence'] = data['sentence']
```

Example data is:

```
                  Audio                                    sentence
0   [[-0.32357552647590637], [-0.4721883237361908]] the kind of them is a relative all the little old
1   [[-0.32357552647590637], [-0.4721883237361908]] More text
```

And (in DF audios) result is:

```
    Audio0       Audio1      sentence
0   -0.323576   -0.472188   the kind of them is a relative all the little old
1   -0.323576   -0.472188   More text
```

Comment: Your solution seems a little bit more generalized!

Comment: The problem is, you have used only 4 values in audio column. I can't manually write 10000 value of 907 rows each.

Comment: @shahidhamdam you haven't to write it manually, it's just an example, to see what's happening. To use this approach you should use code with audios dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step I would generate a list of column names:

```
N = 10000
colNames = ["Audio" + str(i) for i in range(N)]
```

The i would create a second dataframe `df2` from your previous dataframe `df` with:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2[colNames] =  pd.DataFrame(df["Audio"].values.tolist(), index=df.index)
```

This should be really close to what you want, except that every single value is still in a list. So the result should look similar to this:

```
>>> df2
     Audio0                    Audio1                   Audio2
0    [-0.32357552647590637]    [-0.4721883237361908]    ...
1    [-0.32357552647590637]    [-0.4721883237361908]    ...
2    ...
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is flatten each entry of 'df.Audio' and construct a new `DataFrame` with correct column names.

```
# Flatten list in each row
audio_list_flat = []
for nested_list in list(df["Audio"]):
    audio_list_flat.append([y for x in nested_list for y in x])

# Get row with max length, assuming the length of Audio could be different
max_len = max([len(x) for x in audio_list_flat])

# Construct new dataframe
flat_df = pd.DataFrame(audio_list_flat,
                       columns=[f"Audio{i}" for i in range(max_len)],
                       index=df.index)
flat_df["sentence"] = df.sentence
```

This way you can solve this with pure `pandas` without adding more dependencies.